# Is $\{ (x,y) \mid -1\leq y\leq 1 \}$ open or closed?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $$B:= \{ (x,y) \mid -1\leq  y\leq 1  \}.$$
Is it correct to say that $B$ is closed, because $$B^C := \{ (x,y) \mid \lvert y\rvert >1   \}$$ is open?

Comment: it is affirmative

Comment: Yes, that is correct. But you need to make sure that you know why $B^c$ is open.

Comment: A comment: the way you phrased the question makes it sound like you think a set must be either open or closed, whereas it may be both or neither. You might not have meant this, so apologies in advance if I misinterpreted you.

Comment: I indeed familiar with this. Thanks for your comment!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it is correct, but it deserves a proof. To show that $B^c$ is open, note that it is the preimage of $(-\infty,-1)\cup (1,\infty)$ under the map $$\Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R}:(x,y)\mapsto y$$ (where I've supposed that you work in $\Bbb{R}^2$).

Comment: This can be transformed into a probably simplier proof: $B$ is the preimage of $[-1; 1]$ under the same map.

Comment: That's a good point. But the OP seems to want to show that $B^c$ is open.

Comment: Sure. That's why I only made a comment.

Comment: Thank you all for the confirmation !!!